# Speeding up sound check with convolution

Tags: mixing, convolution

Suppose you're maybe a touring band that's going to play a lot of shows in sequence that have very short allotted sound check times. But you also happen to have

1. A portable digital mixer with very powerful master bus convolution engines
2. High quality measurement microphones
3. A studio with well calibrated monitors

Then what are the practical considerations stopping you from mixing the band in your controlled studio environment, and at the day of the show just showing up with your measurement microphone, measuring the house's transfer function and feeding its inverse to your mixer's convolution processor? That way you'd never worry about a bad mix on stage.

I've tried searching for this but I'm having a real hard time with keywords here. Is there any known documentation for an approach like this?

Comment: Beringer a while ago offered an EQ, which could perform such a run with an extra microphone. Doubt that adjusting EQ will suffice in your situation.

Comment: @MS-SPO Was it good though? A "self-calibrating" EQ is a subset of the setup I'm imagining, removing resonances with a low order transfer function, but what i'm describing would also work to cancel out reverberation in the room.

Comment: If I recall correctly this was the model: https://www.thomann.de/gb/behringer_deq2496_ultracurve_bundle.htm . Feedback destroying is said to be one of its features. As you can see, it's currently not available, so perhaps as reused studio equipment. // Please look for tests on "Behringer Ultracurve Pro DEQ 2496", as I'm only finding German ones. // Product descr.+manual:  https://www.behringer.com/product.html;jsessionid=C26AA56FF09CF62A85379EB350AB8C09?modelCode=P0146#

Comment: It seems to me that the most time consuming steps of a live event soundcheck are not the setting of the PA processing or the recall of a scene memorized on the mixing desk. Checking mics positioning, line continuity and patching, etc. is time consuming. In addition, I would think that a convolution engine on the master bus would add embarrassing latency to the the system.

Comment: From my experience, especially in large venues, it is common to have the FOH system tuned by the band sound man with pink noise or sweeps, sound analyzer and speakers processor.

Comment: This is done all the time, except it’s just EQ, delay, and intensity of the signal sent to each element of a line array system instead of convolution. The one thing is the algorithms and microphones are not as effective as ears and brains, so the automatic PA tuning process only gets you 90% there or so.

Comment: Here’s just the first description of the process that I’ve found: https://www.ntnu.edu/documents/1001201110/1266017954/DAFx-15_submission_28.pdf

Comment: I just saw your comment about canceling out room reverb. That is acoustically impossible. No one tries to do that. That said, line arrays do allow for highly directional reinforcement, which means the generation of unwanted reflections can be reduced during the tuning process.